Как правильно сверстать данный блок?
Как сверстать данные блок, нужно ли использовать sidebar или можно просто поделить контент на две части: слева - избранный пост, справа - все посты?
Какой способ здесь использовать - с использованием справа sidebar, а слева избранный пост или просто поделить контент на две части внутри одного section?


Посмотрите на другие страницы дизайна, если там такого же размера sidebar, значит sidebar. Если же нет, то просто разделите.

С точки зрения seo <aside> (или как вы называете сайдбар) тут не уместен. Вообще надо смотреть на то повторяются ли данные секции на других страницах сайта. Это точно две логические секции.
Имейте в виду, что то какими постами должны наполняться данные секции лучше решать SEO специалисту.
